# How to move the element onto a new line? html/css

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, animation

I would like one of the elements that I want to add to start from the new line. Specifically, I am trying to add a new project card but whenever I add that, the element does not start from the new line but instead it shrinks the other projects cards and all of them are on the same line.

For example, this is the original code of the projects:

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,500,800);
.project-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
}
figure.snip1311 {
  font-family: 'Raleway', Arial, sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin: 10px 1%;
  min-width: 230px;
  max-width: 360px;
  max-height: 256px;
  width: 500rem;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #07090c;
  font-size: 16px;
  -webkit-perspective: 50em;
  perspective: 50em;
}
figure.snip1311 * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
}
figure.snip1311 img {
  max-width: 110%;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
figure.snip1311 figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translate(0%, -50%);
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translate(0%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 0 30px;
}
figure.snip1311 h3,
figure.snip1311 p {
  line-height: 1.5em;
}
figure.snip1311 h3 {
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
figure.snip1311 p {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
}
figure.snip1311 .read-more {
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
}
figure.snip1311 .read-more:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
}
figure.snip1311:hover img,
figure.snip1311.hover img {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
  transform: rotateX(-180deg);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0;
  transition-delay: 0;
}
figure.snip1311:hover figcaption,
figure.snip1311.hover figcaption {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) translate(0, -50%);
  transform: rotateX(0deg) translate(0, -50%);
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.35s;
  transition-delay: 0.35s;
}
.hidden{
display:none;
}
.read-more{
cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<section id="project">
                  <div class="container" data-aos="fade-up">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/projects.css">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/text.css">
      <div class="section-title">
        <h2>My Projects</h2>
        <h23>More Coming Soon!</h23>
        </div>
            <div class="project-container">
   <figure class="snip1311"><img src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/d6f6df_dd155c086895409ab4f61f494fa3108b~mv2.png/v1/fill/w_440,h_320,al_c,q_85,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01/footprint.webp" alt="sample94"/>
  <figcaption>
      <h3>Earth Print</h3>
      <p>Do you want to know how COVID-19 has impacted your carbon footprint? Do you want an app that can keep track of your carbon footprint?</p>
      <div class="read-more">Read More</div>
      <p class="hidden">Earth Print lets you actively gauge your impact on the environment and pushes you to do better. Putting a check on your vehicular emissions and your electricity usage, Earth Print helps you track your carbon footprint and provides a platform for friendly competition to better ourselves as a community. The code uses a simple Express REST API to collect info about the user and Carbon Interface's api to perform calculations and estimate a score of a user's impact on the climate</p>

    </figcaption>
</figure>

<figure class="snip1311"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/474x/0c/b9/b1/0cb9b14c4a5eb45cb54e9089ee066aba.jpg" alt="sample98"/>
  <figcaption>
    <h3>Classroom Seating Plan</h3>
    <p>Do you want a program that automatically sets the seats location for your students, based on alphabetical order? Do you want to save the seatlocation of the students into a different file so that you can refer back to it when needed?</p>
    <div class="read-more">Read More</div>
    <p class="hidden">A classroom seating plan that allows the user to select the size of their classroom (6x5 or 3x10) and outputs a visual representation of what their classrrom looks like.
The user can then type the number of students in their class, and the names of the students along with their seat location gets saved into a new TextFile
This makes it easier for the user to refer back to the names and seat location, as there is a whole new file with the information.
The user then has a choice to sort the names into alphabetical order and assign seats like that. If the user wants it that way, then the names are sorted into alphabetical order with seat location.
Seat location changes depending on the classroom size the user selects, and the rows and columns reset, accordingly
The user then has the choice to exit the program. If they choose to do so, the program is ended. If they do not want to exit the program, then the program restarts. Created using Java.</p>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
<figure class="snip1311"><img src="https://l450v.alamy.com/450v/m67xmp/holiday-sale-online-shopping-concept-woman-holding-credit-card-and-m67xmp.jpg" alt="sample98"/>
  <figcaption>
    <h3>Cash Register</h3>
    <p>Wouldn't you want a program that can deal with both pricing the items as well as applying taxes whenever necessary. Some items do not require taxes, and so my program knows how to exactly deal with that kind of situation.</p>
    <div class="read-more">Read More</div>
    <p class="hidden">A Cash Register that accepts 5 values, and prompts the user to type out uppercase or lowercase h before or after the value to include the item value in HST tax. The max amount that a user can enter is below $1000 and a positive number, otherwise it would not be included in the totals. After the user types 5 values, the item values are stored in different arrays. 
One of them is for HST values only, and the other one is for non-HST values only. 
15% tax is then applied to HST values only, and then accordingly, a new item total is provided. A summary total, HST total, and Amount Due are also provided in the end. Created using Java.</p>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
</div>

</section>
```

So I want to **add another project card but this time it should start in a new line or start right under the first card**

What I tried:

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,500,800);
.project-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
}
figure.snip1311 {
  font-family: 'Raleway', Arial, sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin: 10px 1%;
  min-width: 230px;
  max-width: 360px;
  max-height: 256px;
  width: 500rem;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #07090c;
  font-size: 16px;
  -webkit-perspective: 50em;
  perspective: 50em;
}
figure.snip1311 * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
}
figure.snip1311 img {
  max-width: 110%;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
figure.snip1311 figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translate(0%, -50%);
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translate(0%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 0 30px;
}
figure.snip1311 h3,
figure.snip1311 p {
  line-height: 1.5em;
}
figure.snip1311 h3 {
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
figure.snip1311 p {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
}
figure.snip1311 .read-more {
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
}
figure.snip1311 .read-more:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
}
figure.snip1311:hover img,
figure.snip1311.hover img {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
  transform: rotateX(-180deg);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0;
  transition-delay: 0;
}
figure.snip1311:hover figcaption,
figure.snip1311.hover figcaption {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) translate(0, -50%);
  transform: rotateX(0deg) translate(0, -50%);
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.35s;
  transition-delay: 0.35s;
}
.hidden{
display:none;
}
.read-more{
cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<section id="project">
                  <div class="container" data-aos="fade-up">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/projects.css">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/text.css">
      <div class="section-title">
        <h2>My Projects</h2>
        <h23>More Coming Soon!</h23>
        </div>
            <div class="project-container">
   <figure class="snip1311"><img src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/d6f6df_dd155c086895409ab4f61f494fa3108b~mv2.png/v1/fill/w_440,h_320,al_c,q_85,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01/footprint.webp" alt="sample94"/>
  <figcaption>
      <h3>Earth Print</h3>
      <p>Do you want to know how COVID-19 has impacted your carbon footprint? Do you want an app that can keep track of your carbon footprint?</p>
      <div class="read-more">Read More</div>
      <p class="hidden">Earth Print lets you actively gauge your impact on the environment and pushes you to do better. Putting a check on your vehicular emissions and your electricity usage, Earth Print helps you track your carbon footprint and provides a platform for friendly competition to better ourselves as a community. The code uses a simple Express REST API to collect info about the user and Carbon Interface's api to perform calculations and estimate a score of a user's impact on the climate</p>

    </figcaption>
</figure>

<figure class="snip1311"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/474x/0c/b9/b1/0cb9b14c4a5eb45cb54e9089ee066aba.jpg" alt="sample98"/>
  <figcaption>
    <h3>Classroom Seating Plan</h3>
    <p>Do you want a program that automatically sets the seats location for your students, based on alphabetical order? Do you want to save the seatlocation of the students into a different file so that you can refer back to it when needed?</p>
    <div class="read-more">Read More</div>
    <p class="hidden">A classroom seating plan that allows the user to select the size of their classroom (6x5 or 3x10) and outputs a visual representation of what their classrrom looks like.
The user can then type the number of students in their class, and the names of the students along with their seat location gets saved into a new TextFile
This makes it easier for the user to refer back to the names and seat location, as there is a whole new file with the information.
The user then has a choice to sort the names into alphabetical order and assign seats like that. If the user wants it that way, then the names are sorted into alphabetical order with seat location.
Seat location changes depending on the classroom size the user selects, and the rows and columns reset, accordingly
The user then has the choice to exit the program. If they choose to do so, the program is ended. If they do not want to exit the program, then the program restarts. Created using Java.</p>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
<figure class="snip1311"><img src="https://l450v.alamy.com/450v/m67xmp/holiday-sale-online-shopping-concept-woman-holding-credit-card-and-m67xmp.jpg" alt="sample98"/>
  <figcaption>
    <h3>Cash Register</h3>
    <p>Wouldn't you want a program that can deal with both pricing the items as well as applying taxes whenever necessary. Some items do not require taxes, and so my program knows how to exactly deal with that kind of situation.</p>
    <div class="read-more">Read More</div>
    <p class="hidden">A Cash Register that accepts 5 values, and prompts the user to type out uppercase or lowercase h before or after the value to include the item value in HST tax. The max amount that a user can enter is below $1000 and a positive number, otherwise it would not be included in the totals. After the user types 5 values, the item values are stored in different arrays. 
One of them is for HST values only, and the other one is for non-HST values only. 
15% tax is then applied to HST values only, and then accordingly, a new item total is provided. A summary total, HST total, and Amount Due are also provided in the end. Created using Java.</p>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
<figure class="snip1311"><img src="https://l450v.alamy.com/450v/m67xmp/holiday-sale-online-shopping-concept-woman-holding-credit-card-and-m67xmp.jpg" alt="sample98"/>
  <figcaption>
    <h3>TEST</h3>
    <p>Wouldn't you want a program that can deal with both pricing the items as well as applying taxes whenever necessary. Some items do not require taxes, and so my program knows how to exactly deal with that kind of situation.</p>
    <div class="read-more">Read More</div>
    <p class="hidden">A Cash Register that accepts 5 values, and prompts the user to type out uppercase or lowercase h before or after the value to include the item value in HST tax. The max amount that a user can enter is below $1000 and a positive number, otherwise it would not be included in the totals. After the user types 5 values, the item values are stored in different arrays. 
One of them is for HST values only, and the other one is for non-HST values only. 
15% tax is then applied to HST values only, and then accordingly, a new item total is provided. A summary total, HST total, and Amount Due are also provided in the end. Created using Java.</p>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
</div>

</section>
```

So I want the last Card that I added to start from a new line or start right under the first card. Adding `display: block;` doesn't work because then it moves the two cards onto one line and the next two after.

But I want the pattern to go like this: 3 cards on one line, 3 cards on the next line, and so on. **So the max cards that can be on one line can be 3 only** Any Suggestions?

Comment: Consider using [CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) in conjunction with your FlexBox layout. FlexBox is one dimensional. FlexBox is designed to style one single "row" of content. Grid, being two dimensional, will allow you to define the max # of cards per row for every row.

Comment: so adding `display: grid;` instead of `display: flex;` right?

Comment: no, it is much more complicated than that. Read through the resource I linked for you.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like You are new to CSS. Although, You took advantage of Flex, It's good to see.

Now, Inside Flex, There is a collection of flexbox. To make your case better, You can use flex-wrap property to wrap. It would automatically calculate the space and number of show items according to available screen width;

```
.project-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    color: white;
    }
```

Here is [JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/0eL9m8p5/), if you want to play more.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Is there some way that instead of the card starting in the centre in the new line, it would start from right to left?

Comment: @Sidekick1234 Using `justify-content: flex-end` will right-align the cards.

Comment: Removed unnecessary self-promotion.  See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405195